# Use sed with back references

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am trying to remove a space between 2 strings, they are like this:

```
312.2 MB
123.34 KB
487.1 GB
```

I want to change them to:

```
312.2MB
123.34KB
487.1GB
```

I've been trying and I can get:

```
echo "312.2 MB" | sed s/[0-9][[:space:]][GMK]//g
312.B
```

But when I try to do backreferences with `sed`:

```
echo "312.2 MB" | sed s/\([0-9]\)[[:space:]]\([GMK]\)/\1/g
312.2 MB
```

My guess is that there is only one match, and then the back reference is the complete match, but:

```
echo "312.2 MB" | sed s/\([0-9]\)[[:space:]]\([GMK]\)/TRY/g
312.2 MB
```

So, it is not working anymore when I use the `()` to capture the characters

Probably the regex is not completely correct, but I don't know why.

Comment: I don't know why you want to do this, but there should usually be a [space between a number and a unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)#Spaces_and_unit_symbols).

Comment: Parsing a file that is not correctly formatted :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is quoting.

Because you don't quote your `sed` command, the parenthesis `\(...\)` was interpreted by the shell before passing to `sed`.

So `sed` treated them as literal parenthesis instead of escaped parenthesis, no back-reference affected.

You need:

```
echo "312.2 MB" | sed 's/\([0-9]\)[[:space:]]\([GMK]\)/\1\2/g'
```

to make back-reference affected, and get what you want.

Or more simply:

```
echo "312.2 MB" | sed 's/ //'
```

Comment: Worth noting that for removing characters, `tr -d ' '` also works instead of `sed` (but is equivalent to `sed 's/ //g'`).

Comment: I basically *always* put my sed commands in single quotes as a reflex, for roughly this reason. I also tend to use `sed -r`, for extended regular expressions, which means you don't have to escape your parentheses for capturing groups.

Answer (score 4):

You ain't quoting any of your `sed` expressions, that is the main culprit. put quotes around it like `sed ' '`. Or Simply you can get that by following `tr` expression,

```
tr -d '[:space:]' <<< "312.2 MB"
312.2MB

tr -d ' ' <<< "123.34 KB"
123.34KB

tr -d '[:blank:]' <<< "487.1 GB"
487.1GB
```

If you are insisting on `sed`, you can do that by,

```
sed 's/ //g' 
sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g' 
sed 's/[[:space:]]//g'
```

Answer (score 2):

use `bash`:

```
$ txt="32.2 MB"
$ echo ${txt// /}
32.2MB
```